# How to display multilingual (сyrillic) ttf

Tags: libgdx

LibGDX FreeTypeFont does not generate Cyrillic characters  *(this ttf file supports cyrillic)*

```
lateinit var font: BitmapFont
val generator  = FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Font.ttf"))
val parameters = FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter().apply { size = 100 }

init {
    font = generator.generateFont(parameters)

    private val helloLabel = Label("Привет", Label.LabelStyle(font, null))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION 1:

```
FreeTypeFontParameter().applay {
   characters = "Привет"
}
```

default **characters** contains value:

[image]

**DEFAULT_CHARS** - строка содержащая символы ASKII *(this suggests that the Cyrillic alphabet is not included there)*

---

### SOLUTION 2:

```
FreeTypeFontParameter().applay {
   incremental = true
}
```

*I don't know how it works but* **it works**